# How to blur the upcoming and previous widget in PageView builder - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: Weather App]

For now, I have created a weather Widget and added a PageView builder. I want to fade the upcoming and previous widgets in PageView and the current Widget to be more clear. For testing purposes I added blur to the widget which are not in focus.

**Problem::**

> I'm not able to figure out how I can blur the upcoming widget. The
> current and the previous widgets are blured when I swap through them.

Here is my code currently:

**page_view_gallary.dart**

```
class PageviewGallery extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageviewGalleryState createState() => _PageviewGalleryState();
}

class _PageviewGalleryState extends State<PageviewGallery> {
  var listWidgets = [
    WeatherCard(
        isActive: false,
        location: "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        temperature: 15,
        localTimeEpoch: 1675101764,
        weatherState1: "Strong Winds",
        weatherState2: "Cloudy"),
    WeatherCard(
        isActive: true,
        location: "San Andreas, CA, USA",
        temperature: 15,
        localTimeEpoch: 1675101764,
        weatherState1: "Strong Winds",
        weatherState2: "Cloudy"),
    WeatherCard(
        isActive: true,
        location: "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        temperature: 15,
        localTimeEpoch: 1675101764,
        weatherState1: "Strong Winds",
        weatherState2: "Cloudy"),
    WeatherCard(
        isActive: false,
        location: "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        temperature: 15,
        localTimeEpoch: 1675101764,
        weatherState1: "Strong Winds",
        weatherState2: "Cloudy"),
    WeatherCard(
        isActive: false,
        location: "Los Angeles, CA, USA",
        temperature: 15,
        localTimeEpoch: 1675101764,
        weatherState1: "Strong Winds",
        weatherState2: "Cloudy"),
  ];
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.5,
  );

  int currentPage = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: ExpandablePageView.builder(
          controller: ctrl,
          itemCount: listWidgets.length,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            // Active page
            bool active = index == currentPage;
            return _buildStoryPage(active, index);
          }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ctrl.addListener(() {
      int pos = ctrl.page!.round();
      if (currentPage != pos) {
        {
          setState(() {
            currentPage = pos;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ctrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _buildStoryPage(bool active, int index) {
    // Animated Properties
    final double blur = active ? 30 : 0;
    final double offset = active ? 20 : 0;
    final double top = active ? 100 : 200;
    final double bottom = active ? 100 : 200;

    WeatherCard cWidget = listWidgets[index];
    // print("$index, $currentPage");
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
          sigmaX: active ? 2.0 : 0.0, sigmaY: active ? 2.0 : 0.0),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: top, bottom: 100, right: 30),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.red,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  blurRadius: blur,
                  offset: Offset(offset, offset))
            ]),
        child: cWidget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**weather_card.dart**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class WeatherCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String location;
  final int temperature;
  final int localTimeEpoch;
  final String weatherState1;
  final String weatherState2;
  bool isActive;
  WeatherCard(
      {super.key,
      required this.location,
      required this.temperature,
      required this.localTimeEpoch,
      required this.weatherState1,
      required this.weatherState2,
      required this.isActive});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 450,
          width: 250,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 100,
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
          bottom: 100,
          child: Container(
            height: 250,
            width: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 44, 44, 44).withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 2,
                blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ], color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, left: 20, right: 20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    location,
                    style: GoogleFonts.alegreyaSans(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "$temperature",
                        style: GoogleFonts.alegreyaSans(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 64,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "°C",
                        style: GoogleFonts.alegreyaSans(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Sunday, 11 am",
                    style: GoogleFonts.alegreyaSans(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
            top: -100,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/shaddow.png")),
        Positioned(
            top: -300,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/moon_cloud.png")),
        Positioned(
            top: 330,
            left: 50,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 60,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: const Color(0xff5E4FC1),
              ),
              width: 20,
              // color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                "VIEW STATS",
                style: GoogleFonts.alegreyaSans(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 14),
              )),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Current Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To blur the upcoming and previous widgets in a `PageView` in Flutter, you can use a `Stack` widget with a `BackdropFilter` and wrap each child of the `PageView` with the `Stack`.

Here's an example:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
    YourWidgetHere(),
  ],
)
```

Apply this to each child of the `PageView` builder, for example:

```
PageView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
        YourWidgetHere(),
      ],
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same results after adding my widget to `Stack`. It blurs the `current` and the previous widget but doesn't blur the upcoming widget. Is there any possibility I can blur the upcoming and previous instead of the current widget?

Comment: @AsadKareem Did you find the solution to it? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Please wrap your BackDropFilter widget with the ClipRect Widget then this issue will be resolved.
Try out the following example.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp3());
}

class MyApp3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CarouselSlider(),
    );
  }
}

class CarouselSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const CarouselSlider({super.key});

  @override
  CarouselSliderState createState() => CarouselSliderState();
}

class CarouselSliderState extends State<CarouselSlider> {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  late PageController _pageController ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController=PageController(viewportFraction: 0.4,initialPage: _currentPage);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Blur Carousel Slider'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        // Change this to the number of items in your carousel
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentPage = index;
          });


        },
        children:List.generate(5, (index) =>  _buildCarouselItem(index)),

      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCarouselItem(int index) {

    final isSelected = index == _currentPage;
    final blurIntensity = isSelected ? 0.0 : 15.0; // Adjust blur intensity as needed
    final scale = isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.8; // Adjust scaling factor as needed
    print(blurIntensity);
    return Stack(
      //fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('0' * 10000),
        ClipRect(  // <-- clips to the 200x200 [Container] below
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: blurIntensity,
              sigmaY: blurIntensity,
            ),
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
             // width: 200.0,
             // height: 200.0,
              child: const Text('Hello World'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  
  }
}
```